# why img tag doesn't display image that i read src from database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

my code:

```
<img src="<%dtpath.Rows[i][2].ToString();%>" 
     alt="" 
     style="width:173px;height:173px;margin:20px 0px 0px 35px;" 
     class="imagShadow" />
```

how to assign a value from data table to src in asp.net?

Comment: It's unclear what your asking and your code is incomplete. Please provide some more information

Comment: Please edit you post and provide proper info

Comment: Have you tried this `<img src='path/<%# Eval("Image") %>' alt=""/>` ?  if your are saving you images name in database

Comment: if you have image path stored in database table.Then you should write code like this `<img src="<%= dtpath.Rows[i][2].ToString();%>...`

Answer (score 0):

You need to operate with [base64 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), so assign *it* to src property of the image.

For this I can see a couple of solutions:

1. You have image encoded in DB or on disk (with the path in DB), so you donwload it and convert it to base64 encoding via, say, [How can you encode a string to Base64 in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript) (there are also plenty of others)
2. You prepare on the server for every image you already have corresponding file with base64 encoding, so simply download it and assign it to the image.